# How can I use React Context with react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-context

AuthContext:

```
import { createContext } from "react";
export const AuthContext = createContext(null);
```

App.js:

```
const App = () => {
  const isLogin = false;

  if (isLogin) {
    return (
      <RouterProvider router={privateRoute} />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <RouterProvider router={publicRoute} />
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

I try to put `<RouterProvider>` in `AuthContext` like this:

```
<AuthContext.RouterProvider router={privateRoute} />
```

and like this:

```
<AuthContext>
  <RouterProvider router={privateRoute} />
</AuthContext>
```

None of these options worked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has nothing to do with the other. The issue is that `AuthContext` doesn't have any `RouterProvider` property nor is the code you are trying to use actually using a React context `Provider` component and value.

Just wrap the `App` component with the `AuthContext.Provider` component and ensure a context value is passed.

Example:

```
<AuthContext.Provider value={{ ..... }}>
  <App />
</AuthContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use the `AuthContext` with the `RouterProvider` but `AuthContext` have no property or component called `RouterProvider`.

To use `AuthContext` in combination with the `RouterProvider`, you will need to wrap the `RouterProvider` component in a component that consumes the `AuthContext`'s value (*i.e. useContext(AuthContext)*).

Here a snippet to help you out...
In this we are using `AuthContext` value to detemine the value of `routes` and then use it with `RouterProvider`

```js
const App = () => {
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
  const routes = auth.isLoggedIn ? privateRoute : publicRoute;

  return (
    <RouterProvider router={routes} />
  );
};

export default App;
```

inside and you need to wrap the `App` component inside `AuthContext` like ...

```jsx
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthContext>
      <App />
    </AuthContext>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```